# linux: correct typing errors with aliases?

Tags: bash, shell, alias

When I work in the shell and write fast it happens sometimes that I write " c d.." instead of "cd ..". Is there any way (like an bash-alias) to execute "cd .." with my weird spelling?
(I've already tried to create an alias in my .bashrc but bash then says

```
bash: alias: `c d..': invalid alias name
```

because it can only use single-word aliases, doesn't it?)

Thank you 4 your quick help :D

Comment: Aliases can't process arguments, use a function. You can create a function called `c()` that checks if its first argument begins with `d` and then runs `cd`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add this to your .bashrc :D

```
function c() {
    if [ "$1" = d.. ] ; then
        builtin cd ..
    fi
}
```

Comment: In the OP's example, there is no `$2`; the OP intended to type `cd ..`, but instead typed `c d..`. (Also, your quoting is all wrong. `d..` does *not* need to be quoted, whereas `$1` and `$2` *do*.)